# Paying off debt program in Python

Tags: python

I am currently working on a problem which asks to make a program that determines fixed monthly payments to pay off a certain amount of debt.

For some reason, this code enters an infinite loop when I increment the MP value by anything less than 70. And if I use a value of 70 and higher, the recommended monthly payment is way off.

```
def NoDebt(balance, annualInterestRate):

    '''
    balance -> int/float, the amount of debt youre in
    annualInterestRate --> interest rate (divide by % 100 first)
    '''

    balance0 = balance
    month = 0 
    MIR = annualInterestRate/12.0
    MP = 10

    while balance > 0:

        balance = balance0
        MP = MP + 10

        while month < 12:

            MUB = balance - MP
            balance = MUB + (MIR*MUB)
            month = month + 1


    return MP
```

I've run this and just talked through it for a while -- not sure why it's not working.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code and watch the value of `balance`. You can also use a piece of paper and pencil and explicitly step through your code and calculate your variables for each iteration of your loop.

Comment: You assign `balance = balance0`, but `balance0` is set outside of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop only ever executes once:

```
while month < 12:

    MUB = balance - MP
    balance = MUB + (MIR*MUB)
    month = month + 1
```

Once it's done, subsequent iterations of the outer loop won't enter this inner loop.  Because `month` still is and forever will be 12.  So the code just keeps repeating only this, indefinitely:

```
while balance > 0:

    balance = balance0
    MP = MP + 10
```

As long as `balance0` is greater than 0, there's no reason this would ever stop.

You need to reset `month` in the outer loop:

```
 while balance > 0:

    month = 0
    balance = balance0
    MP = MP + 10

    while month < 12:

        MUB = balance - MP
        balance = MUB + (MIR*MUB)
        month = month + 1
```

**Note:** There *may* be other logical errors in your code, but this seems to be a big one.  For example, as pointed out in a comment above, your loop appears to always reset `balance` to the original balance "every 12 months".  It's still strongly advised that you use a debugger, or even pen and paper.  [This](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) can often be helpful reading on the subject.

Comment: Thanks so much -- i just forgot to reset the month outside of the while loop, totally overlooked it as i was reviewing the code